# Why React state doesn't change when appending child nodes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why doesn't the counter increase every time I press the "increase" button? Console.log shows counter value not changing

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Increase({ action }) {
    return (
        <button onClick={ action }>increase</button>
    );
}

function App() {
    
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("counter", counter);
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    };

    const [ childNodes, setChildNodes ] = useState([<Increase action={ handleClick } key={0} />]);
    
    const handleAppend = () => {
        setChildNodes([
            ...childNodes,
            <Increase action={ handleClick } key={ childNodes.length } />
        ]);
    }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={ handleAppend }>Append button</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                Counter value: { counter }
            </div>
            
            <div>
                { childNodes }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I expected the counter to increment each time any button clicked. Including dynamically added buttons.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think that's what the OP is asking. They are (I think) complaining that they click the button to append an Increase, but then clicking that Increase (which renders the button) does not increase the count. I suspect it's a [stale closure problem](https://medium.com/@anandsimmy7/stale-closures-and-react-hooks-ea60689a3544).

Comment: @JaredSmith - Yeah, I'd already deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each instance of `Increase` uses the `handleClick` that was created for the call where that `Increase` was created, and that `handleClick` closes over the `counter` as of when it was created. So the first one always closes over `counter = 0`, for example. So if you add three nodes without clicking any of their "Increase" buttons, they all use `handleClick`s that close over `counter = 0`. Clicking any of them does `setCounter(counter + 1)` which is `setCounter(1)`.

Any time you want to update state based on existing state, use the [callback form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of the state setter so you're dealing with up-to-date state:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter((c) => c + 1);           // <====
};
```

Your original:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Increase({ action }) {
    return (
        <button onClick={ action }>increase</button>
    );
}

function App() {
    
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("counter", counter);
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    };

    const [ childNodes, setChildNodes ] = useState([<Increase action={ handleClick } key={0} />]);
    
    const handleAppend = () => {
        setChildNodes([
            ...childNodes,
            <Increase action={ handleClick } key={ childNodes.length } />
        ]);
    }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={ handleAppend }>Append button</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                Counter value: { counter }
            </div>
            
            <div>
                { childNodes }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Updated to use `setCounter((c) => c + 1)` (and to log `c`):

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Increase({ action }) {
    return (
        <button onClick={ action }>increase</button>
    );
}

function App() {
    
    const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);

    const handleClick = () => {
        setCounter((c) => {
            console.log("counter", c);
            return c + 1;
        });
    };

    const [ childNodes, setChildNodes ] = useState([<Increase action={ handleClick } key={0} />]);
    
    const handleAppend = () => {
        setChildNodes([
            ...childNodes,
            <Increase action={ handleClick } key={ childNodes.length } />
        ]);
    }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={ handleAppend }>Append button</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                Counter value: { counter }
            </div>
            
            <div>
                { childNodes }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```